# Validate Radio Buttons in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to validate some radio buttons using Javascript but I could not get it work. I just want to make sure a user to answer questions by checking radio buttons and leave no question unanswered. Here is the codes:

```
Html
….
Gender:
<input type="radio" id="Male" name="Gender"> Male
<input type="radio" id="Female" name="Gender"> Female

Member:
<input type="radio" id="Mem" name="Member"> Yes
<input type="radio" id="NonMem" name="Member"> No

Vegetarian:
<input type="radio" id="Veg" name="Veget"> Yes
<input type="radio" id="NonVeg" name="Veget"> No
……
```

---

```
function validate()

if (!document.getElementByID("Male").checked && !document.getElementByID("Female").checked)
        {alert("Please specify gender");
        return;}

if (!document.getElementByID("Mem").checked && !document.getElementByID("NonMem").checked)
        {alert("Please specify member");
        return;}

if (!document.getElementByID("Veg").checked && !document.getElementByID("NonVeg").checked)
        {alert("Please specify vegetarian");
        return;}
```

---

Any answers/helps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what 'does not work' currently?

Comment: What I found out was the codes does not work when I tested in Live View using Dreamweaver with my notebook. It keeps popping up the alert "Please specify gender" even though gender was selected. It works perfectly in my server as an html page. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function validate()
{
if (!document.getElementById("Male").checked && !document.getElementById("Female").checked)
        {alert("Please specify gender");
        return;}

if (!document.getElementById("Mem").checked && !document.getElementById("NonMem").checked)
        {alert("Please specify member");
        return;}

if (!document.getElementById("Veg").checked && !document.getElementById("NonVeg").checked)
        {alert("Please specify vegetarian");
        return;}
  alert("successfully validated");
  }
```

```html
Gender:
<input type="radio" id="Male" name="Gender"> Male
<input type="radio" id="Female" name="Gender"> Female
<br>
Member:
<input type="radio" id="Mem" name="Member"> Yes
<input type="radio" id="NonMem" name="Member"> No
<br>
Vegetarian:
<input type="radio" id="Veg" name="Veget"> Yes
<input type="radio" id="NonVeg" name="Veget"> No
<br>
<input type='button' value='Validate' onclick='validate()'>
```

`document.getElementByID` to `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 Gender:
    <input type="radio" id="Male" name="Gender"> Male
    <input type="radio" id="Female" name="Gender"> Female
    <br>
    Member:
    <input type="radio" id="Mem" name="Member"> Yes
    <input type="radio" id="NonMem" name="Member"> No
    <br>
    Vegetarian:
    <input type="radio" id="Veg" name="Veget"> Yes
    <input type="radio" id="NonVeg" name="Veget"> No
    <br>
    <input type='button' value='Validate' onclick='validate();'>
    <script>
     function validate()
    {
    if (!document.getElementById("Male").checked && !document.getElementById("Female").checked)
            {alert("Please specify gender");
            return;}

    if (!document.getElementById("Mem").checked && !document.getElementById("NonMem").checked)
            {alert("Please specify member");
            return;}

    if (!document.getElementById("Veg").checked && !document.getElementById("NonVeg").checked)
            {alert("Please specify vegetarian");
            return;}
      alert("successfully validated");
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mess up small code error BUT your logic is totally right...Just take a look at your code

you used `document.getElementByID` it may be `document.getElementById` ...did you get that ?

Not `ID`.  it's `Id`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just correct the **"TypeError"** in your Javascript code:

Replace:

```
document.getElementByID
```

With:

```
document.getElementById
```